# Pre allocate ether to your account

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

1. I created a genesis file and saved it in a folder called `node1`.
2. Then I entered the following command:

   ```
   geth init "C:\rahul13615\blockchain\node1\genesis1.json"
   ```
3. Folder named `chaindata` was created and certain space was allocated to me.
4. Then I entered:

   ```
   geth --fast --cache 512 --networkid 321 --datadir "C:\rahul13615\blockchain\node1" --identity "FirstNode"
   ```
5. Few more folders like `dapp`, `keystore`, `nodes` and a file named `nodekey` were created.
6. Then I used `personal.newAccount("Test1")` to create a new account on my newly created node.
7. I used the account's address and added the following in genesis file:

   ```
   "alloc": {
       "0xb4c55eae41809524f570be88ef9be0b108b993b8" :
       { "balance": "20000000000000000000" } 
   }
   ```
8. I saved this file and re-entered commands in step 2 and 4 to read the updated genesis file.
9. Then I entered `primary = eth.accounts[0];` this returned me the address of the account I created.
10. Then, `balance = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(primary),"ether")`

Ideally it should return 20 ethers but it is returning 0.
Please help me understand where i went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After you change your genesis file use `--init` option to adopte the new one. However you could mine new blocks `miner.start`() to get new ethers

Answer (score 1):

All the data in the previous blockchain(without account balance) will be stored in the `chaindata` folder. After step 7, you should delete all the files & folders except the `keystore` folder and the `genesis` file. This ensures that you're starting a new private blockchain and not working on the previous one.